# Unable to login using smack XMPP client in Android

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

trying to connect & login using XMPP client in Android. The XMPP client connects to the server but doesn't logs in. I am getting Exception message as No response from the server.

i have google and found the same issue  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596830/unable-to-login-to-ejabberd-server-using-xmpp-client-in-android?rq=1) but its not working for me.

my code is

```
    // Create a connection
    ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(host,
            5222, service);
    XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);

    try {
        connection.connect();
        Log.i("XMPPClient", "Connected to " + connection.getHost());
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPClient", " Failed to connect to " + connection.getHost());
        Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
        xmppClient.setConnection(null);
    }

    try {
        connection.login("username", "userpass", "someresource");
        Log.i("XMPPClient", "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

        // Set the status to available
        Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
        connection.sendPacket(presence);
        xmppClient.setConnection(connection);
    } catch (XMPPException ex) {
        Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to log in as "
                + USERNAME);
        Log.e("XMPPClient", ex.toString());
        xmppClient.setConnection(null);
    }
```

i am unable to figure where the problem is?

Edit: the same code is working fine (loggin the user) from google.com  but not working for my ejabberd XMPP client y?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22675177/trying-to-reach-my-openfire-server-through-my-android-client/22677635#22677635 for proper DNS setup

Answer (score 1):

In the Second Try and catch You have to write as connection.login("UserName","Password");

and after connection .sendPacket(presence); You have to write only as setConnection(connection);

which May be helpful to you.